# Upload username and password to rundeck key storage using CLI / REST?

Tags: rundeck

I want to use username and password in Rundeck to run jobs on node instead of public / private keys. How do I do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rundeck CLI always asks for the user and password by default, also, you can define environments vars `RD_USER` and `RD_PASSWORD` in your `.bashrc` file. Take a look at [this](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/configuration/) (Credentials section).

Example:

```sh
export RD_USER=username
export RD_PASSWORD=password
```

Using API you can use use the "cookie way" to access an endpoint, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#password-authentication).

And check the following example:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

curl -v -c cookie -b cookie -d j_username=admin -d j_password=admin http://localhost:4440/j_security_check \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    http://hyperion:4440/api/31/system/info/
```